# Is it possible to change text color for all headings?

Tags: sectioning, xetex, formatting, color

I want to change only the color (not font size, etc.) of all headings in my documents (`\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, ...). I want to keep all other settings fixed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) allows you to modify sectional heading fonts on a case-by-case basis, or all at once. For example, to modify only the `\subsection` fonts, use `\subsectionfont{<font defs>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\color{green!80!black}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{blue!50!white}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

For all sections, use `\allsectionsfont{<font defs>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\allsectionsfont{\color{black!30!green!50!cyan}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using a [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class you don't need an additional package (besides the color package, of course) but can use `\addtokomafont`. Adapting Werner's examples:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\addtokomafont{section}{\color{red}}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{green!80!black}}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\color{blue!50!white}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Or all sections with the same color:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\color{black!30!green!50!cyan}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```