# Remove Formatting in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, color

I have custom colouring in the section headings, i.e. `\section{\textcolor[red]{Heading}}`, so when I use `\tableofcontents` it prints the table of contents including all the unnecessary colouring. Is there a way I can print the table of contents in all black text, but keep the actual colour coding I did for the sections?

Answer (score 6):

Use the "ToC" entry of `\section[<ToC entry>]{<body entry>}`:

```
\section[Heading]{\textcolor{red}{Heading}}
```

If this is performed on a case-by-case basis, then the above solution is fine. However, for more consistent changes across (say) *all* section headings, you should consider using a package like [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) or [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). For more on this option, see [Is it possible to change text color for all headings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68376/5764)

Comment: Looks like this is the only solution anyone can think of, BUT I also thought of a sneaky solution just now :)! Print the TOC in black and white, and the rest in colour!! :D Thanks for your solution!