# coloring every chapter name in the document

Tags: sectioning, color, chapters

My question is directly related to post-processing using authoring packages like `etoolbox` for instance.
I've included the package as follow :

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

what i try to do is to prepend `\color{myColor}` to every `\chapter` commands in the whole document.
I'm using :

```
\preto\chapter{\color{myColor}}
```

That could actually work, but not only colors my chapter but also all the text after *`\chapter`* commands (therefore all my document..).

Is there some way to wrap the color to only every chapter ?

**ps** : I'm using report class

Comment: This reminds me of another question: [Is it possible to change text color for all headings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68376/is-it-possible-to-change-text-color-for-all-headings)

Answer (score 10):

An example using the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\chapterfont{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
test

\end{document}
```

[image]

And now using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\color{red}}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
test

\end{document}
```

As I see, you added the information that you are using the `report` document class; my example codes will work also for this class.

Answer (score 8):

You probably could patch in a closing group but you need to be careful not to interfere with the way section headings look ahead for `*` or optional arguments. Also putting a color command immediately before the chapter command is quite likely to affect the vertical spacing.

It is better really simply to add the colour at the point the font is added. In book class the chapter head is defined by

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

so I'd do

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \textcolor{myColor}{\@chapapp\space \thechapter}%
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries \textcolor{myColor}{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

Which avoids adding the colour in vertical mode.

---

I see you added a comment that you are using report so you would make the same additions to:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

Comment: When I caught a glimpse of the TeX code here, I didn't need to check whose answer this is.  I just knew... somehow.

Comment: Is there any danger in renewing the relevant `\@startsection` command's sixth argument to contain something like `\color{red}` (between the `\makeat<letter|other>` commands where needed)?

Comment: in principle yes but probably not in practice, I went to some lengths to avoid starting the color in vmode here but I tried to find an example that went wrong with some of the other answers but couldn't come up with one (but it is 1 in the morning so who knows:-)

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness: If you use KOMA-Script you can simply use the font elements. Use `chapter` to affect only the `\chapter` headings or `disposition` do change all section levels.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\color{red}}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\section{My Section}
\subsection{My Subsection}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image: colored chapters]

Answer (score 2):

Since `\color{myColor}` *starts* coloring text "from now on", you might want to do something like

```
\preto\chapter{\begingroup\color{myColor}}
\appto\chapter{\endgroup}
```

This is definitely not a clean way of doing this, but should work.  Instead, I'd look for solutions using `fncychap`, `memoir` or similar packages/classes.

Comment: The best solution for `fncychap` is not using it. ;-)

Comment: Well, I've actually never used it, I only looked at its docs and remembered about its existence.  What exactly is the problem with that package?

Comment: The styles are mostly ugly and some only work well for one liners.

Comment: Well, but there's some support for customization, like font or color changing.  And that's what needed here.  Edit: and I didn't look at predefined styles, btw.