# How to scale fonts including sections and subsections?

Tags: fontsize

I am trying to scale the fonts in my document with the `scalefnt` package. However it only affects the body text and not the section or subsection headings, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}

\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\scalefont{2}
\subsection*{Test}

Test
\endgroup


\subsection*{Test}

Test

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Is there any way to make this work or another way to scale all fonts including section and subsection headings by the same factor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only using `\normalsize` font and standard sectioning commands, then you could use the [`sectsty` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) to easily manipulate font sizes of sectional headings in concert with [`scalefnt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scalefnt).

The following example, with some modifications, is partly taken from [Is it possible to change text color for all headings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68376/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,scalefnt,sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lmodern,scalefnt,sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\sectionfont{\color{red}\scalefont{2}}
\subsectionfont{\color{green!80!black}\scalefont{2}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{blue!50!white}\scalefont{2}}
\AtBeginDocument{\scalefont{2}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section} Hi there
\subsection{A subsection} Some text
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} Some more text
\small Hi there
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, `\small` initiates a different (fixed) font size based on the document class option (`10pt` default in this case), and therefore doesn't correspond to the `\scalefont{2}` set `\AtBeginDocument`; the only caveat.

Comment: Is there a way to use this locally like `\begin{scalefont}{2} text text text \end{scalefont}`?

Comment: @Philip: Yes. Use `some text {\scalefont{2}text text text} some more text`.

Comment: Thank you, it is kind of working, the result is not as beautiful as when you do a global spacing.

Comment: @Philip: Yes, because the baseline skip is not updated until it reaches an explicit `\par` or an empty line. If you're thinking about adding emphasis on certain pieces of text, rather use `\emph` or `{\bfseries ...}`.

Answer (score 6):

You don't say *why* you want to do that. the document size option `12pt` here sets fonts for structural elements like section headings as well as the page size and vertical spacing, you need to change them all together.

Perhaps you want to typeset to a smaller size say `[a5paper]` then scale the document back up to A4 using a pdf2pdf post process, then fonts and vertical spacing scale together.

Comment: I want to make a transparency for an old style overhead projector. Therefore I want to have a easy control over the scaling of the fonts in the document to improve readability.