# Variable color for section titles

Tags: macros, sectioning, color

The following def takes first three letters as an argument:

```
\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\or%
        brown\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}
```

It actually colors first three letters of the section name. How do I make it color the whole section name instead?

Can I make it to take the whole paragraph as an argument?

**Edit**

In order to make it work one has also to

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}
```

**Edit 2**

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\or%
        brown\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
}

\begin{document}


\section{aaaaaa}

\section{bbbbbb}

\section{cccccc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't color anything by itself. I don't find `\@sectioncolor` in `latex.ltx` nor in `(x)color.sty`. Without a minimal example it's impossible to say anything sensible.

Comment: What is `\color{headercolor}`? It is really confusing code.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot: it's `\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}`

Comment: @egreg: see edit.

Comment: What about [Is it possible to change text color for all headings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68376/5764)

Comment: @Werner: but code I post is smater: it changes color of the section name after each section.

Comment: @Adobe: And? You can adapt the code in the those answers to change the colour with every section. That wasn't the point of that question.

Comment: @Werner: You right: issuing `\sectionfont` before each section manually solves the problem. But this brings a problem of turning off section numbers with `sectsty`.

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`

Comment: @Adobe: I'm hoping at this point you can actually reword the question. A title such as "Paragraph as an argument" doesn't seem to be what you're after. Perhaps what you're after is a way to format the colour of a section heading that cycles through a list of colours...

Comment: I don't understand why `\@sectioncolor` has three arguments. It seems you want to color the section title, but what else? Try deleting the arguments `#2` and `#3`. Then, in the definition of `\section`, change the line `\@sectioncolor #1%` to `\@sectioncolor{#1}%` (with braces). If that doesn't do what you want, explain what it is you want.

Comment: @Dan: it gives `! Argument of \@ has an extra }.`

Comment: @Adobe You've solved it, but I should point out that the error about `\@` has nothing to do with your coloring problem. You simply shouldn't use command names with `\@` in them in your document. Or, if you must, then surround the code that includes them with `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sectsty` (or, with some more work, `titlesec`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\newcommand\sectioncolor{%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or
        red\or
        orange\or
        green\or
        purple\or
        brown\else
        headercolor\fi
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
  % Remove the following line if you don't want to cycle
  \ifnum\value{colorCounter}=7 \setcounter{colorCounter}{0}\fi
}

% in section titles \sectioncolor will be executed
\sectionfont{\sectioncolor}

% don't number sections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\section{aaaaaa}

\section{bbbbbb}

\section{cccccc}

\section{dddddd}

\section{eeeeee}

\section{ffffff}

\section{gggggg}

\section{hhhhhh}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's cool solution for a problem, but I hack moderncv template, and have to make as little modifications as possible.

Comment: If the section title appears as the first thing on a new page, this doesn't work as expected: the color for that section title will be always gray and not the next in the specified list

Comment: @Aelius Not in my experiment: I added `\clearpage` before `\section{eeeeee}` and it comes out red as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Oh I solved it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

\newcounter{ColorCounter}
\newcommand\Color{
  \color{%
    \ifcase\value{ColorCounter}%
      blue\or%
      red\or%
      orange\or%
      green\or%
      purple\or%
      brown\else%
      headercolor%
    \fi%
  }
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  {
    \LARGE\Color #1
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}
  \stepcounter{ColorCounter}
}

\begin{document}


\section{aaaaaa}

\section{bbbbbb}

\section{cccccc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course you're not worried about the section title ending up at the bottom of a page and the text in the next one.

Comment: You mean there is a potential buggy behaivior? I'd've read Your book on programming latex, but You've written it in Italian.

Comment: You don't take any precaution, so there's a feasible page break point after your section titles.