# How to use `\textcolor` in section headings?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, color, overleaf, beamer-metropolis

I want to use `\textcolor` in the headings of my sections (see MWE below). My question differs to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68376/is-it-possible-to-change-text-color-for-all-headings) as I don't want to color *all* sections in *one* color (say red) and *all* subsections in *another* color (say green), but *different* sections in *different* colors.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
\section{The \textcolor{red}{red} section}
\section{The \textcolor{green}{green} section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @LianTzeLim I think the overleaf tag is relevant here, because the solution proposed in the MWE works (if frames are added) on all reasonable up to date distributions, but not on the old installation on overleaf

Comment: @LianTzeLim BTW: are there any plans to move overleaf to TL2018?

Comment: @samcarter Ah fair enough, thanks! Yes we'll be moving to TL2018, though I think not by the end of this year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the nice answer of @jfbu on overleaf, which uses some outdated packages,  adding `\protect` before `\textcolor` seems to be necessary.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}

\section{The \protect\textcolor{red}{red} section}
\begin{frame}
 A
\end{frame}

\section{The \protect\textcolor{green}{green} section}
\begin{frame}
B
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: any idea why with no frames but the two sections there is error (on TL2018)? perhaps it is illegal to not have frames in beamer class? (but this may be theme dependent, it works ok without the metropolis theme) (but produces no output) (sorry if my ever extending comment looks confusing)

Comment: @jfbu Coincidently I just wrote a comment about this below your question :)

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem with this. Your MWE was not compilable.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
  \section{The \textcolor{red}{red} section}
\begin{frame}
A
\end{frame}
  \section{The \textcolor{green}{green} section}
\begin{frame}
B
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

edited as per @samcarter request to move the `\section` outside the frames.

Notice that without the frame environment the example does not compile with an "arithmetic overflow" involving `\calc@denominator`.

There is at my local TL2108 no need for `\protect` with `\textcolor` in this use case, but @samcarter reports it is needed on overleaf. Please refer to her answer for more informed comments than mine.

Comment: I have to problems with the answer you gave. 1: it does not work on my "machine" (which is overleaf.com). What compiler (etc.) do you use? 2: it makes the sections as frames with a frame number which I would have to remove and resetting the counter.

Comment: @jfbu Can you please move all the sections outside of the frames? Otherwise this can lead to annoying side effects.

Comment: @Qaswed Overleaf seems to have some old package versions, but you can workaround with `\section{The \protect\textcolor{red}{red} section}
\begin{frame}` (notice the `\protect` and that the section must be outside the frame)

Comment: @jfbu did you try without `\protect` on overleaf?

Comment: @samcarter no, but I am providing here answer for self-standing TeX installations, not for online services which can provide their own hotline.

Comment: @jfbu OK, then I'll add an answer for the special case of overleaf

Comment: @samcarter, yes +1 for doing that please. As per my answer I will remove what I said about `\protect` because yes, there is `\protect\leavevmode` but this can work only once.

Comment: @jfbu I think the calc error might be caused by all these progress bar things the metropolis theme provides, but not sure (and does not really matter anyway)

Comment: @samcarter thanks for that hint. Makes sense.

Comment: jfbu, thank you for your answer, and sorry, I did not point out more early that I'm using overleaf. Since FLonLon added this information to the question, I think picking the answer from samcarter is more correct.

Comment: @Qaswed yes, agreed.